# Docker raise an error when tried to create a data volume

Tags: jenkins, centos, docker, virtualbox

I am trying to use a container to create a Jenkins server. I do my first test creating the container without share or create any data volume. But later I tried to create a data volume for the directory `/var/jenkins_home` and at this moment the docker daemon raise it error:

```
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
```

I am using a VM with VirtualBox with OS ***Centos 7***, and the jenkins images is ***docker.io/jenkins***. This VM has 20G of disk.

If more information is needed to solve this problem let me know.

#### UPDATE

I use the follow command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/lib/jenkins_home docker.io/jenkins
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the line you're using to run the image, and the Dockerfile (if you have it).

Comment: @AssafLavie I did the update that you asked.

Comment: Is your docker using devicemapper? `docker info | grep Storage` will tell you.